# Converting PnP Powershell Online code to SharePoint 2013

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

I've written some code using PnP PowerShell for SharePoint Online, but I now need to port it to SharePoint 2013.  While I had full control on SharePoint Online, I have no Admin rights to SharePoint 2013.

The following code simply iterates through a Site collection and sub-webs and finds lists that support a particular content type. It then outputs the contents of each list into a Report.

I'm confused about connecting to SharePoint on-prem.  Online I'm using:

```
 Connect-PnPOnline -Url $sourceUrl -CurrentCredentials
```

Assuming SharePoint 2013 is running Powershell 5.1, Other than the connection there really isn't much to change? Is there?

```
 Get-SPOnlineFileDetails -sourceUrl "http://intranet.xxxx.gov/km/" -Recurse $true -IncludeFileSize $true | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\Users\wxmuldom\Documents\Data\SPOnlineDetails.csv"

    function Get-SPOnlineFileDetails()
    {
        Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline, HelpMessage="SharePoint Online source site URL")]
            [String]
            $sourceUrl,
            [bool]
            $Recurse,
            [bool]
            $IncludeFileSize      
        )
        Process{
             Write-Host "###################### Pull Details From SharePoint Online ######################" -ForegroundColor Green
             Write-Host "Provided Source URL :"$sourceUrl -ForegroundColor Green
             try{

                     Connect-PnPOnline -Url $sourceUrl -CurrentCredentials
                     $web = Get-PnPWeb

                     PopulateData -web $web -incldeFileSize $IncludeFileSize

                     if($Recurse -eq $false){
                         Get-PnPSubWebs | %{
                          PopulateData -web $_ -incldeFileSize $IncludeFileSize                   
                         }
                     }
                     else{
                         Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse | %{
                          PopulateData -web $_ -incldeFileSize $IncludeFileSize                   
                         }
                     }
                }
                catch{
                Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
                }

        }
    }

    function PopulateData($web, $incldeFileSize){
            Write-Host "Current Site " $web.url -ForegroundColor Cyan 
                      $libs = Get-PnPList -Web $web | Where{($_.BaseType -eq “DocumentLibrary”) }

                      foreach($lib in $libs){
                         $libitems = (Get-PnPListItem -Web $web -List $lib -Fields "FileLeafRef","Name","Title","Author","Modified","Created","KBAbstract","KBContentAuthor","KBCategory","Publish","KBPublishDate").FieldValues

                           foreach($libitem in $libitems)
                             {
                                 if($libitem.FSObjType -eq "0"){
                                  $data = @{
                                              "Web Name" = $web.Title

                                              "Library Name" = $lib.Title
                                              "File Name" = $libitem.FileLeafRef
                                              "Abstract" = $libitem.KBAbstractMicrosoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
                                                $value = $libitem["KBContentAuthor"]
                                                $user = Get-PnPUser -Identity $value.LookupId
                                               "Content Author" = $user.Title
                                               $MMSFieldValueColl = $libitem["KBCategory"] 
                                                #Concatenate each term in the value collection
                                                $MMSFieldTerms = ""
                                                Foreach ($MMSFieldValue in $MMSFieldValueColl) {

                                                    if($MMSFieldValue.label -ne $null)
                                                    {
                                                        $MMSFieldTerms+=$MMSFieldValue.label+"; "
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                Write-Host $MMSFieldTerms

                                             # "Knowledge Area" = $libitem.KBCategory
                                              "Publish" = $libitem.Publish
                                              "Published Date" = $libitem.KBPublishedDate.LookupValue
                                              "File URL" = $libitem.FileRef
                                              "Modified Date" = $libitem.Modified
                                              "Created By" = $libitem.Author.LookupValue
                                              "Created Date" = $libitem.Created
                                              "Modified By" = $libitem.Editor.LookupValue
                                              "File Size (KB)" = $null
                                         }
                                 if($incldeFileSize -eq $true){
                                        $file = Get-PnPFile -Url $libitem.FileRef
                                        $data["File Size (KB)"] = $file.Length / 1KB
                                  }
                                  New-Object PSObject -Property $data
                                }
                             }
                      }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just install the right module. See the installation instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps), and note that there's a different installation  on the PNP modules for each version of SP, including 2013. Note, if you need multiple installations on the same machine, that can get a bit tricky, so see the answers [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266140/how-to-change-versions-of-pnp-powershell) if you need that option.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking to connect to the on-Prem 2013 instance using PnP.PowerShell, use the -TransformationOnPrem -CurrentCredential switches as shown in the [Pnp.PowerShell docs](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html?q=2013#example-11)

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://portal.contoso.com" -TransformationOnPrem -CurrentCredential