# [PnP][SharePoint] How to add a column to all content types of a list?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, column, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have a list in SharePoint with 50 content types. My list has two columns that I want to add to each content type in my list using PNP library. Until now I have something like this:

```
Add-PnPField -List $listTitle -Field $_.Name
```

But I could't find a way to check that "Add to all content types" checkbox from PNP. I've tried

```
-AddToAllContentTypes
```

but i've got this error: **Add-PnPField : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'AddFieldOptions.AddToNoContentType'.**

Any way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `-FieldOptions AddToAllContentTypes` parameter to your `Add-PnPField` command.

For Example:

```
Add-PnPField -List "New list" -DisplayName "New List Column" -InternalName "NewListColumn" -Type Text -Required -AddToDefaultView -FieldOptions AddToAllContentTypes
```

**Source**: [Add-PnPField: Create List Column in SharePoint using PowerShell](https://www.codesharepoint.com/powershell/create-list-column-in-sharepoint-using-powershell)

**Note**:

1. As per the [March 2020 Release](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/releases/tag/3.19.2003.0), They have removed `FieldOptions` argument from `Add-PnPField`.
2. So, you might try using above command by installing [January 2020 Release](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/releases/tag/3.17.2001.0) (v3.17.2001.0) or [February 2020 Release](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/releases/tag/3.18.2002.0)(v3.18.2002.0).

[How to change versions of PnP PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266140/how-to-change-versions-of-pnp-powershell)

Comment: Try suggestions mentioned in my updated answer. I have never tried it but found this useful information on internet. this might help you.

Comment: Hello, indeed this can be a solution but since the project is for a client, i cannot change the version of pnp to an older one. I have tried your solution to the latest pnp version and it's not accepted : **WARNING: Parameter 'FieldOptions' is obsolete. Not in use**

Comment: Yes, because they have removed `FieldOptions` parameter from all releases after February 2020 Release.